# How to move data from Adjust, Funnel and facebook Ads to google big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Can someone provide me the steps to push data from Funnel,Adjust and Facebook Ads to google big query ??
We are not interested in third party softwares like stitch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Assuming you mean Funnel.io here? If so, isn't this what Funnel already does for you? If you are looking to migrate away from that product and do this yourself, you'r going to need to find importers for each of the data sources which Funnel connects too individually. It may be, actually, that you just want to stick with Funnel to make life easier?

BigQuery offers several connectors to external data sources via their [Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer/), while Facebook Ads is not one of the official connectors, Google recently opened up the platform to [third-party connections via the Google Cloud Platform Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/third-party-transfer), which does contain a connector for Facebook Ads.

However, this means you are once again using a third party connection, so may not be what you are looking for.

If you don't want to use third party connections, and there isn't a Google built solution, then your remaining option is to build your own data importer, usually via the data sources API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new in this area . I am asked not to use any 3rd party tools .. Can you guide me any reference for API. I dont see much article related to it